# Surface area of spheres not seen by any other.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I found this question recently looking around the internet, apparently it was on the IMO shortlist many years back. I haven't been able to solve it, and I am looking for hints and/or full solutions. Apparently it can be done very elegantly.

Consider N non overlapping spheres of equal radius placed in 3D space. Let $S$ be the set of points on the surface of these spheres which are not visible from any other sphere. Show that the total area of $S$ is equal to the surface area of one sphere.

Thoughts so far: the problem is trivial in one dimension, and likely equivalent in difficulty in 2D and 3D (it looks like it still holds in 2D, hence I imagine it works for any number of dimensions). It is also obviously true for 2 spheres, and can be verified with some effort for 3. I've had many ideas but none of them have yet led me anywhere I thought promising.

Comment: How is the set of points which are not visible from another sphere defined? Can the "observer" be at arbitrary point of the other sphere?

Comment: @user yes, the point belongs to S if it cannot be seen from any other point on any sphere

Comment: If we have two tangent spheres, one hemisphere of each can be seen from the other.  Suppose all the spheres are tangent, like beads on a bracelet.  Then doesn't it follow that each point of every sphere is visible from some other sphere?

Comment: @saulspatz It does not follow, since if the centers of the spheres $C_i$  lie on the same straight line the bracelet cannot be closed. And if $\angle C_1CC_2\ne\pi$ there is a part of $C$ which can be seen neither from $C_1$ nor from $C_2$.

Comment: @user That makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As I'm seeing it: Let $c_i$ $(1\leq i\leq N)$ be the centers of the given spheres and $P$ be the convex hull of the $c_i$. Then $P$ is a compact convex polyhedron in ${\mathbb R}^3$, bounded by vertices, edges, and faces. Let $$Q:=P+B_r=\bigl\{x+y\bigm| x\in P, \>\|y\|\leq r\bigr\}$$ be the closed "$r$-neighborhood" of $P$. This $Q$ is bounded by a spherical piece for each vertex of $P$, a cylindrical piece for each edge of $P$, and a plane piece for each face of $P$. The spherical pieces are exactly the parts of the given spheres that cannot be seen from some other of the given spheres. The total curvature of these parts is $4\pi$, by Gauss'-Bonnet's theorem. Therefore the total unseen area on the given spheres is $4\pi r^2$, or the area of a single sphere.

Comment: Would this line of argument extend to more than $3$ dimensions?

Comment: @saulspatz: Yes. My argument is related to Steiner's formula for the volume of $Q$ as a function of $r$. See here:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_volume#Quermassintegrals

Comment: I'm afraid this is beyond me, unfortunately.

Comment: Stunning! Also, always funny to see the proverbial "hitting a nail with a sledgehammer".

Answer (score 1):

The set S consists of several pieces corresponding to spheres.

Use translations to move all the pieces to one sphere.

We will prove that 1) the translated pieces do not overlap 2) any point of that sphere (except some set of area 0) is covered by some piece.

For the sake of brevity I will call points A and B equivalent if they lie on different spheres and the translation which takes one sphere to the other takes A to B.

1) If translated pieces have a point in common, that means that there are two equivalent points in S. But this cannot be true (just draw a picture): if A and B are equivalent, the line AB intersects the two spheres in points P, Q. In any possible arrangement of A,B,P,Q on a line either A or B sees some point on the other sphere. (the arrangement cannot be APQB, since then A and B are not equivalent)

[image]

2) draw all possible lines connecting centers of the spheres and for each such line delete the big circle on our sphere perpendicular to the line. Let's prove that for any remaining point there is an equivalent point in S. Let that point be X and the center of our sphere be O. Look in the direction XO. What you see is a bunch of circles. Some of them are close to us and some are remote. Take the closest point. It is equivalent to X and it belongs to S. (We  deleted the circles to be sure that there is only one closest point: if there are two closest points, then they lie on a big circle perpendicular to center line of two spheres)

Comment: I don't like your explanation but the equivalency idea underlies a beautiful solution. How did you come up with this?

Comment: "What you see is a bunch of circles. Some of them are close to us and some are remote. Take the closest point. It is equivalent to $X$ and it belongs to $S$."  Could you add some details? 1) The closest point of what (spheres or circles)? 2) What is the exact meaning of the "closest"? 3) Why is this point equivalent to $X$? 4) Why does it belong to $S$?

Comment: Now I see. Probably you mean the point $Y$ lying on a distant sphere with the largest value $\vec{OY}\cdot\vec{OX}$ (i.e. most distant from the plane containing the point $O$ and orthogonal to $OX$). Nice idea! But if it is so, your description is really confusing.

Comment: @user The closest point of the speheres. "Closest" means the following: introduce a coordinate axis parallel to XO (and directed from X to O) and take the point with minimal coordinate. Let that point be Y. What an observer sees from Y is a half-space, which is bounded by tangent plane at Y. (In other words, the set of points whose coordinate is less than that of Y). So no other spheres are seen from Y which means Y is in S. The fact that X is equivalent to Y is obvious.

Comment: Sorry for unclear explanation, English is not my native language all right.

Comment: English is not my native language too. But I am sure that if we choose a sphere for "projection" of the set $S$, we should place an observer there (at the point $O$)! It is conceptually simpler than to place him every time at a new point  outside of our "galaxy". :) It means the change from "the closest" to "the farthest".

Comment: @Shakespeare Some time ago I solved some problems from a handout with topic "Lattices", where half of the problems were solved by using translations bringing everything to the unit square. So, when I saw this problem i knew what to do. By the way, here's an example of such problem: Let M be the set of points (x;y) of the plane such that the circle with center (x;y) passing through (0;0) contains exactly n integer points. Prove that M has area 1. Very nice problem.

Comment: I can't follow the argument at all.  It seems like a very pretty approach, and I'd like to understand it.  Could the OP, or some else, please post a more detailed explanation?

Comment: First of all, "Use translations to move all the pieces to one sphere."  Is the "one sphere" one of the given spheres, or another sphere, or does it matter?  Second, "call points A and B equivalent if they lie on different spheres and the translation which takes one sphere to the other takes A to B."  If A and B don't lie one the "one sphere" how can translation take A to B?  Do you mean, translation takes A and B to the same point, perhaps?  Third, in part $1)$ you say "just draw a picture", but I must be drawing the wrong one.  Can you supply it? (continues)

Comment: (continued) Is the remainder of part $1)$ after the parenthetical remark supposed to explain what I would see in the picture?  I don't understand the sentence, "the arrangement cannot be APQB, since then A and B are not equivalent."  Why is this?    I appreciate that you are facing a language barrier, and I hope my questions aren't misconstrued.  I don't care about the grammar; I'm trying to get at the ideas.

Comment: @saulspatz I agree with your criticism on the presentation of the proof (and this is the only reason why I still did not upvote this nice and correct answer). The "one sphere" may be any of the given ones or can be "created" separately for the projection procedure of part 2. It does not play a role in the part 1 of the proof where it is shown that two different spheres cannot have equivalent "hidden" points (because at least one of them is seen from the other of the considered spheres).

Comment: @user Would you be willing to post a more comprehensible statement of the solution?  I feel that there is an elegant argument here that I just can't tease out.

Comment: @saulspatz I still hope liaombro will find a way to improve the presentation of the answer.

Comment: @User Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

The following are some preliminary considerations that might help to better focus the problem.

a) For two spheres in direct sight of each other, the visible portions are those contained into the cylinder connecting the two.
b) The visible and dark portions are separated by a major circle, on the plane normal to the line connecting the centers.
c) The problem is not affected by value of the common radius of the spheres: it can in the limit be reduced to zero.
d) For any number of aligned spheres, the hypothesis is true.
e) For three spheres ( a triangle) the dark area of each corresponds to the (dihedral) angle comprised brtween the normals to the sides
thus equal to $\pi $ minus the internal angle: the tesis is true.

[image: Spheres_dark_area_1]

f) Any sphere inside the  triangle is totally visible: the thesis is true for any triangle, containing whatever number of internal spheres.
g) Same for any convex polygon, the dark dihedral angle is $\pi$ minus internal angle, and the total is $(n-(n-2)) \pi = 2\pi$ .
h) Passing to a polyhedron, the dark area will be that included in the solid angle individuated by the planes normal to the edges.
i) The spheres inside a convex polyhedron are again totally visible.
Consider in fact a sphere $\to$ point inside the polyhedron. By definition of convexity, any plane through the point will leave
at least one vertex of the polygon on either side of the plane.  Therefore any point on the internal sphere will see at least one vertex.
j) The same consideration above is valid for any convex polytope.

[image: Spheres_dark_area_2]

k) Given a convex polytope, keeping one vertex (O) firm and moving the other spheres (A) along the prolongation of the edges (B)
won't alter the total amount of dark area, because of the consideration in a):
i.e., $OA$ and $OB$ are equivalent.
The choice of the vertex O is arbitrary, so the projection can be repeated from any vertex in A or B.
l) In addition to the above, any angle-preserving transformation won't alter the situation.

Comment: This seems like the germ of a good approach, but one would like to prove it without resort to spherical geometry.  It seems like the problem should generalize to $n$ dimensions, so we shouldn't rely on specifics of $3$-dimensional space.  I'm thinking along these lines: let $S$ the set spheres whose centers are the vertices of the convex hull of the set of centers.  Then all spheres not in $S$ are completely visible. (Proof?)  Reduce the problem (somehow) to the case where there are no spheres except at the vertices, and solve this case (somehow).

Comment: @saulspatz: fully agree with your considerations: I was also mumbling along the same lines, trying to surpass spherical geometry. I have found [this interesting lesson](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Other/hopf-samelson.pdf) which seems to be on the focus of this problem .. but needs time to be digested.

Comment: I'm now thinking about induction.  When we add another sphere, we have to show that the previously invisible areas of the old spheres that can be seen from the new sphere are precisely balanced by areas on the new sphere that are invisible from the old spheres.  I have a feeling that this is essentially the same as @liambro's solution, but maybe easier to express.  I can't see how to formalize my ideas yet.

Comment: @saulspatz: I made a couple of steps more, I feel we are close to the conclusion in terms of (maybe) affine transformations. Would be glad to have your advise and help.

Comment: I definitely intend to look at this, but the weather is sweltering here, and I won't be able to concentrate until we get some relief, I think.